# Ruby on Rails: Why "edit" action does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

In `views/products/edit.html.erb` I use:

```
<%= form_for(:product, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @product.id}) do |f| %>
```

which generates:

```
<form method="post" action="/aircons/8" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

and I get the following error:

```
The action '8' could not be found for ProductsController
```

when trying to update a product with `id=8`.

I think that form's method should be `put`. Is that right ? How should I fix this ?

---

Some controller code:

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  update_params_with_new_values(params)

  @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
    flash[:notice] = "Product updated successfully."
    redirect_to(:product => 'index')
  else
    render('edit')
  end
end

def update_params_with_new_values(params)
  params[:product][:shop_id] = Shop.create(:name => params[:new_shop]).id if params[:product][:shop_id] == "new_shop"
  params[:product][:brand_id] = Brand.create(:name => params[:new_brand]).id if params[:product][:brand_id] == "new_brand"
end
```

---

`routes.rb` contains only the following two lines:

```
root :to => "products#index"
resources :products
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just use:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
```

?

If it won't work, please add your routes to question.

Comment: OK. It works now :) But, still, the method is POST, while according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions the method for update should be PUT. Why the difference ?

Comment: As I remember, browsers/servers support only POST and GET methods. DELETE and PUT is done using POST. So when you create a form, in HTML it just use POST, but to the form a hidden field is added `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />` by which Rails distinguish which method you use

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
<% form_for @product %>
#code goes here
<% end %>
```

you need not do all the things that you are trying. If you have created this `Product` model using scaffolding mechanism you must have its entry in the `config/routes.rb` file this will give you a path variable as below

```
GET     /products/:id/edit      edit    return an HTML form for editing a photo
PUT     /products/:id   update  update a specific photo
```

you can get the edit path as `edit_product_path` for more info on this [have a look at this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Hope you understand it better now.

Comment: can we have a look at your controller code and also the route for this particular controller

Comment: The controller and the routs look good. No problem with these files. Well I would like to know how are you getting on the edit page. I mean the line of code which links you to the edit page.

Comment: Here it is: `<%= link_to("Edit", edit_product_path(product.id), :class => 'action') %>`